# How to replace Source with other Source in Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

As you can see Number 1 Source has to be Replaced with Number 2 Union Source .There is no option to connect the same line of transformations to new source .How can i achieve this [image]

Comment: The picture is not loading for some reason. you may just need to change the incoming stream in the next transformation. Hope it helps

Comment: yeah how can i miss that .It works

Comment: Grand. if it works would you please upvote my comment !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture is not loading for some reason. you may just need to change the incoming stream in the next transformation. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use incoming stream to achive the same.
Below is an example of how you can implement the same
[image]
**Output:**
[image]